# Data not showing when load the page for the first time

Tags: reactjs

In my react application, I have shown select option. Using following tutorial, learnt Filter Feature as Drop-down [Filter Feature as Dropdown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UVbaLNnX2F0&list=LLg7AckrYeym58O0dSJPFHCQ&index=6&t=0s)

Problem - when load the page for the first time, data is not showing according to select option. Is there any way that I can display the data when load the page for the first time.

Here I have the attached the images and code below - [

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';




class App2 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      courses: [],
      course: ""
    };

    this.handleChangeCourse = this.handleChangeCourse.bind(this);

  }


  handleChangeCourse(event) {
    this.setState({
      course: event.target.value
    });
  };


  getUnique(arr, comp) {
    const unique = arr
      .map(e => e[comp])
      .map((e, i, final) => final.indexOf(e) === i && i)
      .filter(e => arr[e])

      .map(e => arr[e]);

    return unique;
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    const courses = require("./courses.json");
    this.setState({
      courses: courses
    });
  }

  render() {


    const uniqueCouse = this.getUnique(this.state.courses, "tag");

    const courses = this.state.courses;
    const course = this.state.course;

    const filterDropdown = courses.filter(function(result) {
      return result.tag === course;
    });

    return ( <
      div >
      <
      label >
      Select -
      <
      select value = {
        this.state.course
      }
      onChange = {
        this.handleChangeCourse
      } > {
        uniqueCouse.map(course => ( <
          option key = {
            course.id
          }
          value = {
            course.tag
          } > {
            course.tag
          } <
          /option>
        ))
      } <
      /select> < /
      label > <
      div > {
        filterDropdown.map(course => ( <
          div key = {
            course.id
          }
          style = {
            {
              margin: "10px"
            }
          } > {
            course.course
          } {
            course.tag
          } <
          br / >
          <
          /div>
        ))
      } <
      /div> < /
      div >
    );
  }
}

export default App2
```

]
[Image-1-data not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7Bl7.png)

[Image-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moYrH.png)

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidMount()` runs after the initial render. There is no way to show your data on the initial render. You have to wait for the data. Only on your second render, you're going to get the data. Till then you could return `null` from your
render when you don't have the data.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';




class App2 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      courses: [],
      course: ""
    };

    this.handleChangeCourse = this.handleChangeCourse.bind(this);

  }


  handleChangeCourse(event) {
    this.setState({
      course: event.target.value
    });
  };


  getUnique(arr, comp) {
    const unique = arr
      .map(e => e[comp])
      .map((e, i, final) => final.indexOf(e) === i && i)
      .filter(e => arr[e])

      .map(e => arr[e]);

    return unique;
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    const courses = require("./courses.json");
    this.setState({
      courses: courses
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.courses.length === 0) return null;


    const uniqueCouse = this.getUnique(this.state.courses, "tag");

    const courses = this.state.courses;
    const course = this.state.course;

    const filterDropdown = courses.filter(function(result) {
      return result.tag === course;
    });

    return ( <
      div >
      <
      label >
      Select -
      <
      select value = {
        this.state.course
      }
      onChange = {
        this.handleChangeCourse
      } > {
        uniqueCouse.map(course => ( <
          option key = {
            course.id
          }
          value = {
            course.tag
          } > {
            course.tag
          } <
          /option>
        ))
      } <
      /select> < /
      label > <
      div > {
        filterDropdown.map(course => ( <
          div key = {
            course.id
          }
          style = {
            {
              margin: "10px"
            }
          } > {
            course.course
          } {
            course.tag
          } <
          br / >
          <
          /div>
        ))
      } <
      /div> < /
      div >
    );
  }
}

export default App2
```

Comment: I'm curious. When does the second render happen?

Comment: `re-renders` happens whenever you `setState` in your Component. In your case, that would be `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 0):

You should set the initial state in the constructor instead of in componentDidMount:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      courses: require("./courses.json"),
      course: ""
    };

    this.handleChangeCourse = this.handleChangeCourse.bind(this);

  }
```

To understand what happens, here is a nice lifecycle diagram of a react component: https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/981712092611989509/photo/1